# vertical headings table - header and row same color

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical heading html table where i am trying to have the heading and row be the same color, but alternating. The picture illustrates what i want.

[image]

Here is my table

```
  <table class="dialogTable" cellspacing="0" style="height: 450px">
    <caption><h4>Validation Results</h4></caption>
    <tr>
        <th width="250px">Source Records</th>
        <td width="400px">{{dialogData.totalNumRecords}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th width="250px">New Records</th>
        <td>{{dialogData.numNewRecords}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th width="250px">Updated Records</th>
        <td>{{dialogData.numUpdatedRecords}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th width="250px">Removed Records</th>
        <td>{{dialogData.numDeletedRecords}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th valign="top" width="250px">Error Message</th>
    <td class="dialogstyle" valign="top" >
        <div class="errortext" ng-repeat="error in dialogData.errors" valign="top">{{error}}</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the css i have

```
.dialogTable {

overflow-y:hidden;
margin-left: 6px;
}

.dialogTable > th:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #eee !important;
}

.dialogTable > th:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

right now the headings are all the same color.
Thank you

Comment: why not just use bootstrap?

Comment: does bootstrap have a class that achieves this?

Comment: yes. see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#tables under striped rows

Comment: does it also stripe the headers?

Comment: yes :) but you might need to redesign how your table is structured. If that will take more time then just use one of the answers.

Comment: @buzzfizz Why use an entire CSS framework for such a small effect?

Comment: I already have striped rows. What i needed was the stripped heading with those stripped rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to be like this

```css
tbody tr:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: #EBEBE8;
  color: #666666;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(even){
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #666666;
}
```

```html
<table class="dialogTable" cellspacing="0" style="height: 450px">
    <caption><h4>Validation Results</h4></caption>
    <tr>
        <th width="250px">Source Records</th>
        <td width="400px">{{dialogData.totalNumRecords}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th width="250px">New Records</th>
        <td>{{dialogData.numNewRecords}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th width="250px">Updated Records</th>
        <td>{{dialogData.numUpdatedRecords}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th width="250px">Removed Records</th>
        <td>{{dialogData.numDeletedRecords}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th valign="top" width="250px">Error Message</th>
    <td class="dialogstyle" valign="top" >
        <div class="errortext" ng-repeat="error in dialogData.errors" valign="top">{{error}}</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this works for the rows not the headings. Do you think i have something conflicting?

Comment: For heading, you have to give individuals with the class name. where exactly you want on `<h4>` heading?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want the whole row and you're on the right track, but you're just targeting the `th` instead of the whole row.

Try `tr` instead of `th`:

```
.dialogTable > tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eee !important;
}

.dialogTable > tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

Maybe start with just one of those styles, to make sure your `nth-child` selector is working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking for .dialogTable as the direct parent. Which it is not. Try this instead. Also, your code only colors half of the row. Use the table row instead.

```
.dialogTable {
overflow-y:hidden;
margin-left: 6px;
}

.dialogTable tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #eee !important;
}

.dialogTable tr:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The selectors are wrong. It should be

```
.dialogTable tr:nth-child(even) {
   //add bg colour
}
.dialogTable tr:nth-child(odd) {
   //add bg colour
}
```